# division by zero with a template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template

```
template<size_t N>
class Foo {
    int bar(int a) {
        if (N == 0)
            return 0;
        return a / N;
    }
 }
```

when I instantiate this with 0

```
Foo<0> bar;
```

gcc is too smart and reports division by zero at compile time

I tried

```
class Foo<size_t N> {
    template<size_t M>
    int bar(int a) {
        return a / N;
    }

    template<>
    int bar<0>(int a) {
        return 0;
    }
 };
```

but this gives me error:

error: explicit specialization in non-namespace scope 'class Foo'
error: template-id 'bar<0>' in declaration of primary template

any ideas how I could solve/workaround this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a template specialization for `Foo<0>`.

```
template <>
class Foo<0> {
public:
    bool bar () { return true; }
};
```

If you only want to address the issue with `bar` alone, and not touch any other part of `Foo`, you can create a companion method to avoid the issue:

```
template <size_t N>
class Foo
{
    bool bar(int n) {
        if (n == 0) return true;
        return 5 / n == 1;
    }
public:
    bool bar() { return bar(N); }
};
```

Or pull the implementation of that method out into its own class, and specialize that:

```
template <size_t N>
class Bar
{
public:
    bool operator() const { return 5 / N == 1; }
};

template <>
class Bar<0>
{
public:
    bool operator() const { return true; }
};

template <size_t N>
class Foo {
    bool bar() { return Bar<N>()(); }
};
```

Alternatively, you can use Jarod42's suggestion, and specialize the method itself (answer reiterated here for completeness).

```
template <size_t N>
class Foo
{
public:
    bool bar() { return 5 / N == 1; }
};

template <> inline bool Foo<0>::bar() { return true; }
```

Comment: this is just a example - my class is way bigger than just this one method

Comment: @gsf Then specialize the method the way Jaord did.

Comment: Unless the problem is only with one or two methods, I would generally prefer to specialize the entire class for the base case.

Comment: it is just one method from a really big class

Comment: didn't realize you could specialize a single method of a template class...  I can simplify some of my code now!

Answer (score 5):

You can always rethink the formula:

```
template<size_t N>
class Foo {
    bool bar() {
        return N == 0 || (N >=5 && N < 10);
    }
 }
```

Comment: Dammit. Exactly what I wanted to propose. +1

Comment: I think this is the best approach. There is no need for extra code.

Comment: It's good for this specific situation - the individual function specialization is a better general answer.

Comment: yes, this is example formula. My real case is way more complicated. I should be more careful when I try to generalize.

Answer (score 3):

You may specialize the method:

```
template <size_t N> class Foo
{
public:
    bool bar()
    {
        return 5 / N == 1;
    }
};

template <>
bool Foo<0>::bar() { return true; }
```

[Live example](https://ideone.com/52y8ci)

To avoid multiple definitions, you have to define the function only once, or use inline, so

```
// In header
template <>
inline bool Foo<0>::bar() { return true; }
```

or

```
// In header: declaration of the specialization
template <>
bool Foo<0>::bar();

// in cpp: definition of the specialization.
template <>
bool Foo<0>::bar() { return true; }
```

Comment: still looking into it, but the first try gives me: multiple definition of `Foo<0u>::bar()'

Comment: @Jacob42 have you tried this before. I am unable to make it work